# Convert textarea into TinyMCE

Tags: wp-editor

This code converts the textarea into the TinyMCE editor:

```
  $('.text_editor').each(function(){
      var textfield_id = $(this).attr("id");
    window.tinyMCE.init({  
        mode : "none",
        theme: 'advanced',
        skin : 'wp_theme',
        width: "600px",
        height: "300px",
        theme_advanced_blockformats: 'p,address,pre,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6',
        theme_advanced_buttons1: 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,removeformat,|,link,unlink,anchor',
        theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
        theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: 'bottom',
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,            
        });
      window.tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, textfield_id);

  });

<div class="tinymce-tabs">
    <a class="html editor1">HTML</a>
    <a class="visual editor1" class="active">Visual</a>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
 </div>
    <textarea id="text_editor" name="text_editor" class="text_editor"></textarea>
    $(this).prev('.tfuse-tinymce-tabs').find('.html').click(function() {
        window.switchEditors.go(textfield_id, 'html');
    });
    $(this).prev('.tfuse-tinymce-tabs').find('.visual').click(function() {
        window.switchEditors.go(textfield_id, 'tmce');
    });

.tinymce-tabs {
    height: 30px;
    width:600px;
}

.tinymce-tabs .html, .tfuse-tinymce-tabs .visual {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-color: #dfdfdf #dfdfdf #dfdfdf;
    color: #999999;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 5px 5px -2px 0px;
    padding: 4px 5px 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    line-height:15px;

 }

.tinymce-tabs .active {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border-color: #cccccc #cccccc #e9e9e9;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Not able to switch the editor and show the quicktags. I have seen some plugin creates the editor dynamically.

Comment: Do you know [`wp_editor()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)?

Comment: wp_editor is used in php? I need to use the editor frontend and customize the editor toolbar buttons.?

Comment: I was trying mode textareas because of it all the editors showing the toolabr. I made mode to none and it was applied to the editor I call in execCommand

Comment: The problem here is I cannot use the wp_editor. The theme builds all the option fields and the print at one time. wp_editor when I use with buffering it gives unformatted editor